# PostgreSQL: Group records from a single table according to its hierarchy and return the result as a json

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently trying to dynamically obtain information about the structure of my database for a REST API endpoint.

At first I already had a query that provides me with such data:

```sql
SELECT
    table_catalog as catalog,
    table_schema as schema,
    table_name as name
FROM
    information_schema.tables as tables
WHERE
    table_type != 'VIEW'
AND
    table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
ORDER by
    table_catalog ASC,
    table_schema ASC,
    table_name ASC
```

Output:

```
catalog   |schema          |name                       |
----------|----------------|---------------------------|
foo       |account         |hubspot_owners             |
foo       |account         |invitation                 |
foo       |account         |organizations              |
foo       |account         |password_recovery          |
foo       |account         |users                      |
foo       |categorytree    |category                   |
foo       |changelog       |change                     |
foo       |common          |cities                     |
foo       |common          |countries                  |
foo       |common          |industries                 |
foo       |common          |language                   |
foo       |common          |places                     |
foo       |filesystem      |files                      |
foo       |public          |casbin_rule                |
foo       |public          |schema_migrations          |
foo       |scorecard       |candidates                 |
foo       |scorecard       |candidates_skills          |
foo       |scorecard       |dimensions                 |
foo       |scorecard       |interviewers               |
foo       |scorecard       |interviewers_verticals     |
foo       |scorecard       |interviews                 |
foo       |scorecard       |interviews_questions       |
foo       |scorecard       |interviews_skills          |
foo       |scorecard       |questions                  |
foo       |scorecard       |questions_skills           |
foo       |scorecard       |questions_verticals        |
foo       |scorecard       |skills                     |
foo       |scorecard       |sub_dimensions             |
foo       |scorecard       |sub_dimensions_verticals   |
foo       |scorecard       |verticals                  |
foo       |supplybooster   |contributions_contributors |
foo       |supplybooster   |contributions_files        |
foo       |supplybooster   |contributions_repositories |
foo       |supplybooster   |contributions_summary      |
foo       |supplybooster   |scroll                     |
foo       |supplyboosterapi|assignees                  |
foo       |supplyboosterapi|contributor_notes          |
foo       |supplyboosterapi|contributor_references     |
foo       |supplyconnect   |profile                    |
foo       |supplyconnect   |profile_active_availability|
foo       |supplyconnect   |profile_badge              |
foo       |supplyconnect   |profile_communication      |
foo       |supplyconnect   |profile_education          |
foo       |supplyconnect   |profile_experience         |
foo       |supplyconnect   |profile_focus_role         |
foo       |supplyconnect   |profile_portfolio          |
foo       |supplyconnect   |profile_skill              |
foo       |supplyconnect   |profile_spoken_language    |
```

Now I would like to know if there is any possibility of obtaining these same results, but nesting them according to its own hierarchy (`catalog` -> `schema` -> `table`).

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        label: "foo",
        schemas: [
            {
                label: 'account',
                tables: [
                    { label: 'hubspot_owners' },
                    { label: 'invitation' },
                    { label: 'organizations' },
                    { label: 'password_recovery' },
                    { label: 'users' }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'categorytree',
                tables: [
                    { label: 'category' }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'changelog',
                tables: [
                    { label: 'change' }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'common',
                tables: [
                    { label: 'cities' },
                    { label: 'countries' },
                    { label: 'industries' },
                    { label: 'language' },
                    { label: 'places' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I know I could at any moment do such transformation after retrieving the data from DB, but I was wondering if I could take advantage of functions like `array_to_json`, `array_agg`, `row_to_json`, etc to do it entirely through SQL.

The furthest I managed to get so far was in this query below, but I already had to put an unexpected `limit` clause.

```sql
select
    array_to_json(
        array_agg(
            row_to_json(
                catalogs
            )
        )
    ) as data
from
    (
        select distinct
            tables.table_catalog as label,
            (
                select
                    *
                from (
                    select (
                        tables.table_schema
                    )
                    from
                        information_schema.tables as tables
                    limit 1
                ) as lol
            ) as schemas
        from
            information_schema.tables as tables
        where
            tables.table_type != 'VIEW'
        and
            tables.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
    ) as catalogs
```

Output:

```
data                                       |
-------------------------------------------|
[{"label":"foo","schemas":"public"}]       |
```

Is there any succinct way to achieve this? And even if it exists, would it be recommended from a performance point of view?